# how to display results from search box in masterpage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, master-pages

i have a search-box in masterpage, in asp.net project and i dont know two things:

1) how to transfer the results to a new page (because its in master page)

2) how to display the results?

for the first question i tried creating a Session with the DataTable of the answers and in new page (which is built on the master page) on the pageload function check if the Session !=null but it doesn't work well becuase the pageload function is before the masterpage function.

for the second question i tried this:

```
users += "<div class='divusers'>";
users += "<h5>" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + "</h5>";
users += "<h5>" + dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() + "</h5>";
users += "</div>";
```

but is there a better way to show the results?

Comment: If you have two questions - you better create two separate questions. That's the format expected here on SO

Comment: what is the type of result  (a single value or somthing)?

Comment: could you please give more info about how search implemented ?

Comment: the result is a dataTable which contains several rows, each row is a person

Comment: you want to show results in master page or in the content page ?

Comment: the search is in navbar in masterpage, the user put string in a TextBox and when he click the button, i search for users in database which their name contain the string, the results are in DataTable, each row is a person (firstname, username etc...). I want to show the results in a new content page

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to transfer results you just need to send search string to the page, try this
On search button click in master page

```
protected void SearchButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("~/SearchPage.aspx?searchTerm="+txtSearchter.Text);
}
```

On the page load of the results page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     string SearchTerm = Request.QueryString["searchTerm"];
     //Do database search and bind to a gridview
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the master page you can put a control to display the results.

```
<div class="divusers">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h5><%# Eval("columnName") %></h5>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And then on the aspx of the page that is using the Mater, use FindControl to locate the control on the master page and bind the data to it.

```
protected void SearchButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rep = this.Master.FindControl("Repeater1") as Repeater;
    rep.DataSource = DataTable;
    rep.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: when you say in the aspx page you mean the server side of the master page? Because i cant do a SearchButton_Click when the search button is clicked from a regular aspx page that built on the master page, it doesnt recognize the button.

Comment: Not very clear of me sorry. It is on the page that is using the master page, not the master itself.

Comment: i can't do the searchbutton_click function becuase the button is on the masterpage and not in the correct page.

Comment: I thought the search button was on the child. But if the button and Repeater are on the same page you can access it directly without FindControl. `Repeater1.DataSource = DataTable; Repeater1.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

It is better to show the result in Dialog(Popup) instead of Transfering it to new page

```
<GridView>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" Visible="True" />
//other Boundfields
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Search">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button Id="Searchbtn" runat="server" Text="Search" onClick="Searchbtn_Onclick"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
</GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Searchbtn_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind the gridview
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFun1", "javascript:ShowDialog(" + "'Result " + "');", true);
}
```

then in Script

```
script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowDialog() {
       $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            hide: "puff",
            show: "slide",
            width: "70%",
            modal: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").find("form").remove();
                $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');

            }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    }
```

Comment: how do you transfer data to the javascript function? and in the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock what is "MyFun1"?